# What are several examples of survey questions which have response options designed as mutually exclusive when they are not?

Tags: experiment-design, survey, research-design

Statisticians and Data Analysts sometimes draw conclusions from surveys given to people.

Often times, there is a question, and there are 2 to 5 options to choose from if you are a survey respondent.

One of the mistakes people make when writing these surveys is asking survey respondents to choose exactly one option at the same time as providing answer options which are not mutually exclusive.

What are example of real-world survey questions which have been put to people which had non-mutually exclusive answers to choose from?

Comment: This looks rather like a homework question.

Answer (score 3):

A common example is discrete counts with overlapping class-limits. For example: How many days did you visit Stack Exchange in the last month?

- 0
- 1
- 2-5
- 5-10
- more than 10

The problem is this...which option do I pick if I visited exactly 5 days?

Answer (score 0):

This is a community editable wiki.

Feel free to insert additional examples at the bottom

---

## Example One: Video Content

> ### The Question
>
> > Which of the following are you?
> >
> > 1. Video Content Creator
> > 2. Business Video Creator
> > 3. Educational Video Creator
> > 4. You Create Videos for Personal-Use, and/or Family and/or Your Friends".

One problem with mutual exclusivity is that the word "***content***" is an all-encompasing umbrella-like or blanket-like term.

All of the following are sub-categories of **content**:

> 1. business content
> 2. educational content
> 3. videos for personal use, family & friends.

All videos, of any kind constitute video content.

---

## Example Two : [insert your description here]

> ### The Question
>
> > Are you willing to edit this wiki?
> >
> > 1. Yes
> > 2. No
> > 3. Uncertain
> > 4. ?
> > 5. ??

The problem is that ...

Comment: There is no requirement that ALL survey questions have mutually exclusive responses.  It is perfectly reasonable to allow respondents to select more than one answer.  (As such, it seems to me the first example might fall in this category.)  However, when there is supposed to be only one answer, then non-mutually exclusive responses are clearly problematic.

Comment: A made-up "example" of a bad survey question would seem to add little to the thread beyond what's already in the question.  Useful answers would cite surveys that have been published and analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

One classic mistake is assuming that something is a binary, when it's not.  Giving only two options, assumed to be mutually exclusive and complete, makes the survey difficult to answer when reality is in-between or outside the binary in some way.

When things are multifaceted and non-mutually exclusive, survey questions must reflect that: Allow for choosing multiple among multiple options, including self-specified and no-op.